# List<SObject> Cast to List Concrete type

Tags: apex, batch, sobject

I have a `List<sObject> scope` and I want to cast it to a concrete type: `List<My_Concrete_Type__c>`

I tried `scope.getSobjects('My_Concrete_Type__c')` but this doesn't compile. How can I get a `List<My_Concrete_Type__c>`?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried doing this?

```
List<My_Concrete_Type__c> concreteTypeList = (List<My_Concrete_Type__c>) scope;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return an iterator of a specific type from your `start` method and avoid the need to cast entirely.

```
public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<MyObject__c>
{
    public List<MyObject__c> start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return [/*query*/];
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<MyObject__c> concreteScope)
    {
        // execute logic
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        // finish logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely the preferred method when possible.

Comment: @sfdcfox Do you know if it costs you any governors? You can return 50M when using a `QueryLocator`, but I'm not sure if that holds or not with this strategy. I haven't found time to experiment myself.

Comment: Actually, you'll want to use `implements Database.Batchable<SObject>` and `start( ... List<MyObject__c> scope)`, along with the Database.QueryLocator return type. The compiler doesn't actually verify the scope parameter has the same sobject type as the interface sobject type.

Comment: Hmm. I thought it didn't allow me to do that the first time I tried and haven't checked since. I'll have to experiment after all.